# How do you check if a variable is numeric (without isnumeric) and raise error if it is not in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, isinstance

I don't understand why the following does not operate correctly and raises errors when radius or height are float numbers.

```
def cone(radius, height):
    if isinstance(radius, int) or isinstance(radius,float) == False:
        raise TypeError("Error: parameters radius and height must be numeric.")
    if isinstance(height, int) or isinstance (height,float)== False:
        raise TypeError("Error: parameters radius and height must be numeric.")

    if radius > 0 and height > 0:
            return ((radius*radius)*(3.1415)*(height/3))
    if radius<=0:
        raise ValueError("Error: radius must be positive.")
    if height <=0:
        raise ValueError("Error: height must be positive.")
```

Comment: What values are you passing? Where's your unit tests?

Comment: Also `== False` is only being evaluated on the right side of the or

Comment: Because the `if` is evaluated as: `if (isinstance(radius, int)) or (isinstance(radius,float) == False)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: `if not isinstance(radius, int) and not isinstance(radius, float):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want

```
if not (isinstance(radius, int) or isinstance(radius,float)):
```

Or actually

```
if not isinstance(radius, (float, int)):
```

Currently your logic is this

```
if isinstance(radius, int) or (isinstance(radius,float) == False):
```

So, if you got an int, then you get the error. If you get a float, you get no error because you end up with `False or (True == False)`

Anything `or False` is the same as `bool(Anything)`, which in this case, `True == False`, which is `False`

Also, I suggest raising all errors and checking conditions first.

Then just return the actual math because there's no way the variables couldn't be positive at that point

Answer (score 2):

You can pass multiple types to `isinstance`, so you can get rid of `or`:

```
def cone(radius, height):
    if not isinstance(radius, (float, int)):
        raise TypeError("Error: parameters radius and height must be numeric.")
    if not isinstance(height, (float, int)):
        raise TypeError("Error: parameters radius and height must be numeric.")

    if radius > 0 and height > 0:
            return ((radius*radius)*(3.1415)*(height/3))
    if radius<=0:
        raise ValueError("Error: radius must be positive.")
    if height <=0:
        raise ValueError("Error: height must be positive.")

for value in [(1, 2), (0.33, 'foo')]:
    print(cone(*value))
```

Output:

```
0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/s.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(cone(*value))
  File "/private/tmp/s.py", line 5, in cone
    raise TypeError("Error: parameters radius and height must be numeric.")
TypeError: Error: parameters radius and height must be numeric.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `if` is evaluated as:

```
if (isinstance(radius, int)) or (isinstance(radius,float) == False)
```

and I guess this is not what you meant.

Anyway, you can actually make your code simpler by using `try/except`. You can just *assume* your arguments are numbers and do the comparison to `0`. If they are not, an exception will be raised so you can catch it:

```py
def cone(radius, height):
    try:
        if radius > 0 and height > 0:
            return ((radius*radius)*(3.1415)*(height/3))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Error: radius and height must be positive.")

    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("Error: parameters radius and height must be numeric.")
```

Comment: Depends on the objects being passed and if they implement `__gt__`... Checking types would be safe, or using type hints would be better